# Pass ListView's multiple SelectedItems as a command parameter

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, command

I've managed to pass multiple selected items as a parameter to the command this way.
In my view:

```
<Button Command="{Binding MyCommand}" 
        CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItems, ElementName=MyListView}" />
```

Then in `MyCommand`'s `Execute` method:

```
var itemsList = (parameter as ObservableCollection<object>).Cast<FtpListItem>().ToList();
```

And this solution is working for now but I would like to know if I can access multiple `SelectedItems` from a `ListView` in a better way. Possibly in the first expression I can get a `null` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can expect the parameter to be an `IEnumerable`. I would go for the following:

```
IEnumerable enumerable = parameter as IEnumerable;
if (enumerable == null)
    throw new ArgumentException("parameter has to be an IEnumerable.", "parameter");

var items = enumerable.OfType<FtpListItem>().ToArray();
```

Alternatively, you could try some custom `ICollectionView` implementation. The following blog posts discuss your problem and possible solutions in detail:

[MVVM and multiple selection part I](http://grokys.blogspot.com/2010/07/mvvm-and-multiple-selection-part-i.html), [II](http://grokys.blogspot.com/2010/07/mvvm-and-multiple-selection-part-ii.html), [III](http://grokys.blogspot.com/2010/07/mvvm-and-multiple-selection-part-iii.html), [IV](http://grokys.blogspot.com/2012/02/mvvm-and-multiple-selection-part-iv.html)